# Laravel: public/index.php missing

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set up an app with Laravel, when I run **php artisan serve** and go to **https://localhost:8000/** I get these errors:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/**/laravel/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dispatcherplus/laravel/server.php on line 19
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/dispatcherplus/laravel/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/**/laravel/server.php on line 19

Comment: Have you installed fresh laravel and didn't made any changes?

Comment: Yes, I recently installed Laravel and haven't made any changes.

Comment: Then, it should work, its obvious that Laravel setup won't come with error, you might missing something.

Try giving permission

Comment: when you go into the public directory, is the index.php file there?  If not then download a fresh copy from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php

Comment: Hi Mark, /public directory was missing, thank you.