# Laravel 5.8.38 public/index.php missing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, public, serve

It seems to be similar with this question [Laravel: public/index.php missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894627/laravel-public-index-php-missing)
But unfortunately there is no answer.

I have a project that is running on service.
But when I copied the full source code to local and run cmd
`php artisan serve`,
there is fatal error.
The error messages are as follows.

> Warning:
> require_once(E:\Work\Laravel\03_Dev/public/index.php): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> E:\Work\Laravel\03_Dev\server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'E:\Work\Laravel\03_Dev/public/index.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> E:\Work\Laravel\03_Dev\server.php on line 21

Actually there is no index.php in public directory.
But the service is running well.
What do you think the reason is?
Please help me.

PS: The document root directory contains "index.php, .htaccess, server.php"
The public directory(in root dir) contains only "favicon.ico, robots.txt, routes.php, web.config" as files.

Comment: because the person who setup the server originally thought it would be a good idea to compromise the security of the site and move the contents of the public folder into the root.  You could move the files back (so that it works with artisan serve) but then your local copy won't match the server.

Comment: when you run artisan serve it will search for /public/index.php as its defined in server.php line 21  so you can create an index.php file inside public folder and point it out from the server.php file